# On-Demand-Resources download speed from AppStore vs TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight, on-demand-resources

I'm implementing Apple's On-Demand-Resources in my app and I'm testing it using TestFlight. Is there someone who can answer if download speed when using App Store hosting environment is higher than TestFlight environment? It takes 3-4 min to download files 20-40 MB using WiFi or high speed cellular connection, it's ridiculously slow... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For our project we found that the App Store version seems to download the assets pretty fast. Our files are around 20MB as well and we have around 34 assets on the apple server.